# How to modify elements in Java's Linked List in constant time while iterating through it?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to iterate through Java's implementation of a linked list and modify each element of the linked list in constant time. I'm aware of the set() method of linked list but that operation is O(n). So if I used the set() method in a loop it would be O(n^2) which isn't what I want. Since I'm iterating through the linked list, I already know the position of the node of which I want to modify it's contents. Is there a way for me to do this in constant time using Java's Linked List?

I've done this many times with custom implementations but I don't see a way to do this in constant time. I tried iterating below but I'm missing something.

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
Iterator iterator = list.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.remove();
    iterator.set(); // using set() wouldn't be O(1)
}
```

Comment: @KevinAnderson I meant to type list.set() instead. Although there is a set()  method using list iterator which I didn't know about till now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Iterator` does not have a `set` method. Fortunately, you're working with a `LinkedList`, and [`ListIterator` *does* have a `set` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

```java
ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  it.set("new_" + it.next());
}
```

Comment: Best answer, using advantages of LinkedList. Nobody today seems to know what this actually is anymore.

Comment: Would using the set() method replace the content of a node in the LinkedList in constant time (let's just consider a single iteration)? I'd want to be able to change the contents of every node in a linked list in constant time using a loop (so an O(n) time complexity overall).

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of a `ListIterator`: it deals directly (i.e., in O(1) time) with the list nodes,